# Yeoman and php files?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, yeoman

Is there any way to configure Yeoman (latest version: v0.9.6) to serve php files?

I found this http://fgnass.github.com/2012/08/30/yeoman.html but couldn't get it working.

Installed https://github.com/fgnass/gateway, https://github.com/fgnass/tamper and made the required updates to Yeoman as shown here: https://github.com/fgnass/yeoman/commit/39faa07375ee49d56bd50d334dcfd6b5a4e96292.

All i got is the browser downloading each php file instead of rendering it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Yeoman 1.0 has been launched. I haven't tried using php with it yet but would still like to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote a blog post on [Using Yeoman 1.0beta3 with PHP](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2013/04/using-yeoman-with-php.html). 
It seems http://fgnass.github.com/2012/08/30/yeoman.html is not updated for yeoman 1.0.

My code is available on [Github](https://github.com/revathskumar/yeoman-php).
You can look into the [git commit](https://github.com/revathskumar/yeoman-php/commit/7a9338d26e1cd722668ec9dcbe0bf5320cd103a3) for the whole set of changes required for serving php files.

Currently I updated only for connect/livereload tasks.
I am working on updating it for build, usemin and other tasks.

**UPDATE : 1**

It seems there is an easy workaround with [grunt-php](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php).
I haven't used it, but will update once I used it.

Thanks,
Revath

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but your problem seems more a webserver issue. You have to make sure that the webserver processes the files instead of serving them.
If your are using a vhost to map your server [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html) can be a nice read.
Please tell me if this is your problem.